# Hive : Use OR in JOIN

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I am having one dataset

[image]

and another lookup table

[image]

with the help of below query

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, a.RefC4, b.RefC4, c.RefC4
from Tab1 LEFT OUTER JOIN  (
      SELECT * from Ref1 where RefC2 = 'A1') a on Col2 = RefC3
     LEFT OUTER JOIN  (
      SELECT * from Ref1 where RefC2 = 'A2') b on Col3 = RefC3
     LEFT OUTER JOIN  (
      SELECT * from Ref1 where RefC2 = 'A4') c on Col4 = RefC3;
```

I am getting below dataset

[image]

I have 45 values against which lookup needs to be done in order to enrich other columns, in this example (Col5, Col6, Col7). If I use left outer join, query become too long and difficult to maintain. I tried multiple ways but due to one or other hive restrictions I am not able to resolve in shorter and optimize way.

I can't use `OR` with joins and I don't want to use row_number() as this increase turnaround time.

```
Select ....
from Tab1 LEFT OUTER JOIN  (
      SELECT * from Ref1) a on  (RefC2 = 'A1' and Col2 = RefC3) 
      or (RefC2 = 'A2' and Col3 = RefC3)
      or (RefC2 = 'A4' and Col4 = RefC3);
```

Please suggest any other way to write this query in optimize and shorter way.

Comment: The problem is your data structure.  You are storing values in columns rather than in rows, and that makes it hard to process.

Comment: I can understand, the data structure is bit complex but is there any way to resolve in efficient manner

Comment: Will it help if I transpose the lookup table?

Comment: . . It would help if you transpose *both* tables.